# int const array cannot be written to

Tags: c, constants

Compiling the following program

```
int main(void) {
    int const c[2];
    c[0] = 0;
    c[1] = 1;
}
```

leads to error: assignment of read-only location ‘c[0]’. As I understand it, the const only applies to the location of c and so c[0] and c[1] should be mutable. Why is this error produced?

Comment: "int const array cannot be written to" Indeed, that is the purpose of `const`.

Comment: Oh btw, ` int const c[2];` with semicolon and no initializer list is kind of a language bug. The C language allows you to declare a constant without initializing it. C++ does not.

Comment: To get the behavior you describe in the question you could write `int (*const c)[10];` `*c[1] = 5;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As I understand it, the const only applies to the location of c

No. You can't modify the location of the array anyway. What you probably mean is if you have a `int * const`, then that indeed is a constant pointer to a modifiable `int`. However, `int const c[2];` is an array of 2 constant ints. As such, you have to initialize them when you declare the array:

```
int const c[2] = {0, 1};
```

In constrast:

```
int main(void) {
    int c[2];
    int* const foo = c;
    foo[0] = 0;
    foo[0] = 1;
    //foo = malloc(sizeof(int)); doesn't work, can't modify foo, as it's constant
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you write "int const" or "const int", does it? I have never seen "int const" written before. (I am aware that this was taken over from the question.)

Comment: the order does not matter in this case.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `const int` and `int const` are equivalent - the latter is weird style. `const int*` and `int * const` however, mean different things.

Comment: (We can even write `const const const int x`. Because.... C...)

Comment: In this example the `const` has to be at the end, so it applies to the pointer, and not the `int`. It always applies to what's left of it, except when it is already the leftmost thing, then it applies to what is right of it.

Comment: @Blaze All that matters is if it's on the left or right side of the `*`. Your "left of it" rule doesn't hold. Consider `auto const const int const signed const x = 0;`